# Creating a Maze using Java

Tags: java, recursion, depth-first-search, maze

Im using Java to create a maze of specified "rows" and "columns" over each other to look like a grid. 
I plan to use a depth-first recursive method to "open the doors" between the rooms
(the box created by the rows and columns).

I need help writing a openDoor method that will break the link between rooms.

Comment: Before writing an `openDoor` method, we need a couple of basic objects that describe the room and the relationship between them (the doors?). Can you show your definition of the maze in terms of data objects?

Comment: are you trying to CREATE a maze or FIND a way thru maze?

Comment: I am wanting to create the maze and then later find a way through it. Tho at the moment I am stuck on writing the method to openDoors between "rooms".

Comment: Im parsing in the current row and column along with the direction (North East South West) into my method. I also have the total number of rows and columns in the class. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this : [example](http://math.hws.edu/xJava/other/maze.html)

Answer (score 1):

Because you mention depth-first(-search) (DFS) I assume, your maze is a graph where nodes represent rooms. The nodes are connected if there is an unlocked door between rooms. The graph may be cyclic.

You have a start room and may be looking for something in the maze. So you enter a room, check every door, whether it is unlocked or you have key that fits and open every possible door. You may find a key. Then you add that key to your keyring and restart in the start room.

Formally (adapted from [de:wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/wiki/Depth-First_Search#Algorithmus_.28formal.29); see also [en.wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)):

```
DFS(node, goal)
{
  if (node == goal)
    return node;
  else if (node.contains(newKey)) 
  {
    addToKeyRing(newKey);
    resetMaze();
    DFS(startRoom, goal);
  } else 
  {
    stack := expand (node) // all unvisited rooms that can be entered pushed on stack
    while (stack is not empty)
    {
      node' := pop(stack);
      DFS(node', goal);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Yes, the links are the ones I used for the answer.